# IBus >= 1.5.11 on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, versioning

I'm running Ubuntu 15.04. I have the newest version of IBus installed, so does the command show:

```
apt-get changelog ibus
```

But the software I use (PHPStorm 10) gives a warning that IBus with version at least 1.5.11 is recommended. How can I install it?

Comment: You have the version that shipped with ubuntu 15.04, not the latest version, see: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=ibus

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Installed now these builds 
https://launchpad.net/~tista/+archive/ubuntu/wayland/+build/8264511

Download the following files in a folder

```
gir1.2-ibus-1.0_1.5.11+git20151104-2-0ubuntu1~xenial1_amd64.deb
ibus_1.5.11+git20151104-2-0ubuntu1~xenial1_amd64.deb
ibus-gtk_1.5.11+git20151104-2-0ubuntu1~xenial1_amd64.deb
ibus-gtk3_1.5.11+git20151104-2-0ubuntu1~xenial1_amd64.deb
libibus-1.0-5_1.5.11+git20151104-2-0ubuntu1~xenial1_amd64.deb
```

Install

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

Don't pay attention to the warnings and restart

Comment: this was very useful for me! thank you +1.

Comment: Install went smoothly for me. Can't tell yet if the infuriating bug with the keyboard suddenly stopping in PHPStorm is finally over... But if that don't work or for those who can't upgrade ibus, uninstalling ibus completely fixed the problem for me in the past, without much negative side effects (despite non-US keyboard).

Comment: Thanks. Works on Ubuntu 15.10, too. I didn't notice a negative side effect so far.

Comment: I did the `dpkg` but the installation seems to have failed in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS: `Errors were encountered while processing:
 gir1.2-ibus-1.0:amd64
 ibus
` even though `ibus version` displays `IBus 1.5.11` now.

Comment: Yeah, something went wrong, I had Ubuntu warnings that packages were badly installed and I had to open the **Software Center** which *dealt* with the issue. But I lost the Settings menu for instance and had to reinstall it following this https://askubuntu.com/questions/453440/missing-system-settings-after-removing-some-packages (`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`) but then I got `Ibus 1.5.5` back again.

Comment: Great! thank you very much. although the download site is here: https://launchpad.net/~tista/+archive/ubuntu/wayland/+build/8927526

Comment: **One-liner for the lazy ones:** `mkdir -p /tmp/ibus && cd /tmp/ibus && curl -O http://launchpadlibrarian.net/234615974/gir1.2-ibus-1.0_1.5.11-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb -O http://launchpadlibrarian.net/234615976/ibus-gtk_1.5.11-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb -O http://launchpadlibrarian.net/234615975/ibus-gtk3_1.5.11-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb -O http://launchpadlibrarian.net/234615978/ibus_1.5.11-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb -O http://launchpadlibrarian.net/234615979/libibus-1.0-5_1.5.11-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb && sudo dpkg -i *.deb`

Answer (score 4):

Based on some of the comments, I chose to install ibus 1.5.12. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, and based on the reply from @Fabio, this worked for me here is the source location: https://launchpad.net/~tista/+archive/ubuntu/wayland/+build/8927526

```
gir1.2-ibus-1.0_1.5.12+git20160201-0ubuntu1-xenial1_amd64.deb
ibus_1.5.12+git20160201-0ubuntu1-xenial1_amd64.deb
ibus-gtk3_1.5.12+git20160201-0ubuntu1-xenial1_amd64.deb
ibus-gtk_1.5.12+git20160201-0ubuntu1-xenial1_amd64.deb
libibus-1.0-5_1.5.12+git20160201-0ubuntu1-xenial1_amd64.deb
```

---

EDIT - errors with dpkg
Errors when de-packaging are probably related to unmet dependencies.
Download from [Ubuntu-Packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) the missing packages.
Manually de-package until dependencies are met.
Then try de-packaging the above packages again.

Answer (score 1):

After downloading the packages from https://launchpad.net/~tista/+archive/ubuntu/wayland/+build/8927526 
and then running `dpkg -i *.deb` on the downloaded packages, run

`apt-get install -f`

to fix the errors that happened during the dpkg install (some dependencies are missing).

Can confirm it working on Ubuntu 15.10

Answer (score 1):

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04.5 and ran into the same problem with Android Studio. I prefer to upgrade ibus if possible. Turns out, it was very easy^^.

1. Update `sources.list` with these two lines:

   ```
   deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
   deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
   ```
2. Update ibus:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install ibus
   ```
3. Remove the added lines from `sources.list`.

Before updating `sources.list`:

```
sudo apt-cache policy ibus
ibus:  
  Installed: 1.5.5-1ubuntu3.2  
  Candidate: 1.5.5-1ubuntu3.2  
  Version table:  
  *** 1.5.5-1ubuntu3.2 0  
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main 
amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.5.5-1ubuntu3 0
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

After updating ibus:

```
sudo apt-cache policy ibus
ibus:
  Installed: 1.5.11-1ubuntu2
  Candidate: 1.5.11-1ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 1.5.11-1ubuntu2 0
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.5.5-1ubuntu3.2 0
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
     1.5.5-1ubuntu3 0
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

^^Too easy. I'm suspicious that something's going to explode shortly.